# Question on partitions

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I've just started renting a dedicated server which has 2 3TB Hard drives in Raid1. I've just noticed that my home folder only shows as having 1.7 TB of space. Running lsdisk I get the below result. Am I right in thinking the hard drives have been partitioned? And how can I go about getting back to one 3 TB storage volume in Raid 1? I'm new to Linux so any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text and apply code formatting instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/home` partition is assigned a 1.7TB partition on the 2.7TB drive, with a `/` partition having 1024GB, and an 8GB swap partition, and a 512MB `/boot` partition.  This is why you have a 1.7TB `/home` partition.

If you want to change the partitioning layout, talk to the Dedicated Server host, since you're renting it from them they have physical access to change the partitioning layout.

Note that them changing the partitioning layout *may* mean data loss.  We can't really help you fix something on their systems, when they're the ones that did the partitioning and you don't have the ability to boot into a method to mess with partitioning.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have just spoken to their tech support and I can edit the partitions from their Rescue System.  Is my setup the default for Ubuntu or left over from the previous owner? The server came without an OS installed and I installed Ubuntu from their control panel.

Comment: That's the 'installed by the system' version.  I'm hesitant to suggest messing with partitions especially on a RAID system, so I'd suggest you wait for someone else with more experience to come and help you with guidelines to resize partitions.  Note though that combining `/`, `/boot`, and `/home` to maximize space is a no-go, you'd have to do a complete reformat and installation with manual installation steps.